# jQuery UI Autocomplete not working with codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, jquery-ui, codeigniter, autocomplete

I'm trying to get a field on my view to autocomplete with values from a database but can't seem to figure out what is going wrong....

In my view I have the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $( "#searchQuestion" ).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({ url: "<?php echo site_url('contentmanagement/suggestions'); ?>",
                data: { term: $("#searchQuestion").val()},
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
        });
    });
});
```

Within my contentmanagement controller I have the "suggestions" function:

```
function suggestions() {
$this->load->model('onlinehelp');
$term = $this->input->post('term', TRUE);

if (strlen($term) < 2)
    break;

$rows = $this->onlinehelp->GetAutocomplete($term);

$keywords = array();
foreach ($rows as $row)
    array_push($keywords, $row->question);

echo json_encode($keywords);}
```

And Finally within my model I have the follow function -

```
function GetAutocomplete($term) {
        $this->db->select('question');
        $this->db->like('question',$term, 'both');
        $query = $this->db->get('question');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

The query above is the equivalent to "SELECT question FROM question WHERE question LIKE %$term%.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong with this??

Comment: In Firebug or whatever developer tools you're using, what does the JSON response look like coming back from the server?

Comment: Your seems fine at first glance. I suppose you need to add some debugging statements and look through the request using something like Firebug.

Comment: The code seems to get as far as the model getAutocomplete and fails there - the error message i get is "Call to a member function on a non-object" I don't see what the problem is because the $term variable is getting passed fine?

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting a 500 Internal Server Error caused by CSRF protection being enabled. If so, every `POST` request must contain a CSRF value. You have a few options:

**1.** Include the CSRF value in your data using `$this->input->cookie('your_csrf_name');`

**2.** Perform `GET` request instead of `POST`.

Use `$this->input->get('term', TRUE);` in your controller. Remember to sanitize and validate the value.

**3.** Disable CSRF protection. Not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

This works with the CSRF enabled:

Use the jquery cookie plugin

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>/js/lib/jquery.cookie.js'></script>
```

Then on your autocomplete thing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$(function() {
    $("#searchQuestion").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({ url: "<?php echo site_url('contentmanagement/suggestions'); ?>",
                data: { term: $("#searchQuestion").val(), ci_csrf_token: $.cookie("ci_csrf_token") },
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#searchQuestion").val(ui.item.term);
            return false;
        }
    })
    .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li></li>" )
                    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                    .append( "<a>" + item.term + "</a>" )
                    .appendTo( ul );
    };
  });
});</script>
```